# jQuery to track events with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to use jQuery to find all links on a page, then when they are clicked track the event with Google Analytics.

I have the link part working, I'm just not seeing the tracking work event fire (when monitoring with httpfox).

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery and GA</title>

<!-- This Jquery reference is already on the page -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This script block should go anywhere on the page, ideally the head, or really ideally in the a master scripts file -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

// Each time a link is clicked, this function gets called
$('a').click(function(){

// Get the url
var url = this.href;        


// Set the category to External link, unless it matches the portal link/url pattern (containing /community/), 
// in which case category gets set to whatever word follows /community/ in the path.
var category = "External link";
var matches = url.match(/\/community\/([^\/]+)/);
if (matches) {
category = matches[1];
}
alert(category);


// Get the link text
var linkText = $(this).text().trim();
alert(linkText);


// Alert the url, just for the order below's sake
alert(url);


// Track the click
//$(this).attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'," + category + ",'click','" + linkText + "','" + url + "'])");
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'," + category + ",'click','" + linkText + "','" + url + "'])


//return false;

});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Simulating links on Site</h1>

<ul>
<li><a href="http://inet.asdf.asdf.pvt/portal/server.pt/community/home/_articleviewer?ArticleId=s_011610">Read more</a></li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24902347-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing too many parameters to the `_gaq.push()` function. It can only take 3 string arguments, but you're passing 4.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'," + category + ",'click','" + linkText + "','" + url + "'])
     //                  |    category   | action|     label        |    value   |
```

Combine 2 of the arguments to be one, and it'll work (or get rid of the "click" string for action, since its a waste). But, you're also not passing the variable names; you're just passing strings that are equivalent to the variable names. It looks like you're actually trying to do something like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category,  linkText , url]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**yahelc**'s answer should help you get the right params into the event tracking, but it looks like you're missing a closing `</script>` tag before the `</body>` which likely means that GA isn't working at all yet.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can streamline the whole thing with data attributes and a jquery plugin: https://github.com/pascalvgemert/jquery-analytics-event-tracking.